# How do you work with XML collections in SSRS?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, dataset

As the title states, I am unsure of how to work with XML collections and would appreciate any examples that can be provided.

My example is the following:

You have a Data Source pulling Rows from a table within a database. One of the fields in the Dataset returned from the database contains XML

`<Root>
  <Item1>Test</Item1>
  <Item2>
    <Item3>95 Points</Item3>
    <Item3>269 Points</Item3>
    <Item4>
     <Item5>Gold Star</Item5>
     <Item5>Silver Star</Item5>
    </Item4>
  </Item2>
 <Root>`

In a Dataset, you can specify the Fields as `Item1` and `Item2 (Item2 contains a collection of Item3 and Item4 (which contains a collection of Item5))`.

I know the following - In an expression placeholder, you can access the contents of `Item1` Using the following

`=First(First!Item1.Value, "XmlDataSet)`

What I need to know now

1 - How would I access the content of all `Item3` Elements in `Item2`, will `=First(First(Item2.Value, "XmlDataSet").Item3.Value, "XmlDataSet)` Work?

2 - If not, are there alternative methods I can take to this approach, (as in, is it a must that you must use flat XML files in SSRS)?

Answer (score 0):

I always break down the XML on the SQL side into columns. 
You can access the XML nodes by using the XQuery function.

SELECT

```
 [XMLColumnName].value('(/Root//Item1/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'Item1' ,
 [XMLColumnName].value('(/Root//Item2/Item3/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'Item3_1',
 [XMLColumnName].value('(/Root//Item2/Item3/node())[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS 'Item3_2'
```

FROM tableName

Hope this helps.

Comment: worth a shot. Will require some major tinkering to implement this and also require an extra dataset in my report, but, you gave me a lead to work on.